# adding extra params into URL when page loads

Tags: php, redirect, preg-replace

i am passing a url as a param value via URL.
http://www.domain1.com?url=http://domain.com 
i would like to set conditions for adding additional param to a querystring of that passed url. (for example: if domain is 111.com, foo=123 should be added). 
i tried

```
$url = preg_replace('{http://www.111.com}','http://www.111.com?foo=111/',$_GET['url']);
$url = preg_replace('{http://www.222.com}','http://www.222.com?foo2=222/',$_GET['url']);
```

but this is not working when there is a file name or other params.
....any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider different approach without preg_replace at all.

First parse the url with http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$url = '//www.example.com/path?googleguy=googley';    
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url); // will contain parsed parts of the url as array with keys. domain is under 'host' key
```

Then do your logic and decide what you want to add

```
if ($parsedUrl['host'] === 'www.example.com') {
    $queryParts[] = '123';
}
```

Afterwards construct the final url with concating and build query. http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

```
$queryParts[] = $parsedUrl['query']; // keep original query part also.
$newUrl = sprintf(%s%s%s, $parsedUrl['host'], $parsedUrl['path'], http_build_query($queryParts))

echo $newUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this in PHP

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']){
    case 'www.111.com':
         $_GET['url'] =  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'foo=111';
    case 'www.222.com':
         $_GET['url'] =  $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'foo=123'
}
```

and so on, that's if I didn't misunderstood the question, hope it helped

Comment: hi antonio. your answer is helpful thanks. the problem is the url is a value in in the url= param. its not the 'SERVER_NAME'. so it has to parse that last param and add an additional trailing string to it.

Comment: so you're sending a URL let's say 'www.111.com' in $_GET['url'] and you need to evaluate it and add other stuff to it??

Comment: yes. if the domain matches a criteria then its should add values

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is of the regex then try this below. It would add text EXTRA to your url. You can then do whatever with it.

```
 <?php

$url=array("http://www.222.comasdjkasdjkasjd","http://www.111.com123123123");

foreach($url as $eachurl) {
        echo preg_replace('/(http:\/\/www.*?com)/i','$1'."EXTRA",$eachurl);

}

?>
```